# Regular expression for allowing specific URLs

Tags: regex

Regex is very confusing especially for long urls. Here is a code that that checks an URL and stores a customized message in $msg variable. In this example, it allows all URLs except facebook. I need to make some changes.

It should allow all URLs, it should NOT allow facebook url except the ones that has videos

```
if(some url website link){
        $msg = 'url allowed';
    }elseif(preg_match("|^http(s)?://(www.)?facebook.([a-z]+)/(.*)?$|i", $url)){
        $msg = 'url NOT allowed';
    }else{some other url test
}
```

https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=100000000000000 should be allowed. How to I write the regex for allowing only video URL of facebook and not other URLs of facebook.

I want to do this for one more fb URL too like
https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/100000000000000 (should be allowed)

Thank you

Comment: You won't know, if the latter url is a video or not, so your problem starts even before thinking of a valid regex.

Comment: facebook.com/video.php followed by some random strings would be a video url. similarly facebook.com followed by some username followed by posts followed by some random numbers would be a post url. Other than video and post url, no other facebook url should be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match all `facebook.com` URLs that are not videos or status updates:

> `^http(s)?://(www\.)?facebook.([a-z]+)/(?!(?:video\.php\?v=\d+|username/posts/\d+)).*$`

**Explanation:**

```
^                    # Assert position at the beginning of the line
http(s)?://          # The protocol information
(www\.)?             # Match 'www.'
facebook\.           # Match 'facebook.'
([a-z]+)             # Match the TLD
/                    # A literal forward slash '/'
(?!                  # If not followed by:
 (?:                 # Start of non-capturing group
 video\.php\?v=\d+   #   a video URL
 |                   #   OR
 username/posts/\d+  #   a status update URL
 )                   # End of non-capturing group
)                    # End of negative lookahead
.*                   # Match everything until the end if above condition true
$                    # Assert position at the end of the line
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dF5iP1/1)

Comment: wonderful information. really appreciate it. I need to go through this to understand each and every parameter. I will come back to you. thank you.

Comment: Looks like it has become the other way round. I was assuming that this expression will allow only video and posts nothing else but it is allowing developers.facebook.com, /photo.php?fbid=100000000000000, /about, /help, /mobile, /badges, /directory, /careers, /policies, /policy.php, /legal, /privacy... almost everything. Can a regular expression be worked out ONLY to accept Videos and Posts? facebook.com OR facebook.com/anything should NOT be allowed. Only /video.php?v=100000000000000 and /someusername/posts/100000000000000 should be allowed

Comment: @user3736026: Yes, that's how I made it. See the note above the regex: "*match all facebook.com URLs that are **not** videos or status updates*". So in order to match ONLY videos and posts, you'd do: `if (!preg_match('regex', $url)) { ... }`. Note the negation `!`.

Comment: dont know what is happening... I tried the regex again WITH and WITHOUT negation.... WITHOUT negation, (original solution) almost all facebook urls were allowed along with video and post... and now WITH negation all the urls are NOT allowed. Im pretty much sure that I did it properly... I just replaced the reqex in question ^http(s)?://(www.)?facebook.([a-z]+)/(.*)?$ with the one you provided WITH and WITHOUT negation.

Comment: @user3736026: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. If you want a regex that allows only video URLs and status URLs, and nothing else, you can use this: `^http(s)?://(www\.)?facebook.([a-z]+)/(?:video\.php\?v=\d+|username/posts/\d+)$`.

Comment: Anyway, can you share the PHP script (paste it in eval.in) you're using to test this regex?

Comment: Trying to share but now it says unknown modifier 'r' in eval.in https://eval.in/191119

Comment: @user3736026: You're using the pipe (`|`) as the delimiter, so you must escape it inside the regex. Better yet, you can use a different delimiter, such as `~`, or `#`. With the updated regex, your code would look like: https://eval.in/191232

Comment: syntax like these confuse me a lot. Nevertheless, please see the revised example: https://eval.in/191418 .... Here, condition 1 and 2 are correct as per desired result. I thank you for your help and correcting the code. However, condition 3 should be valid as it is a valid post (i guess the term "username" is the problem as usernames can be different) Also I need condition 4 to be true as it is a valid page and condition 5 to be true as it is a valid photo (sorry i did not tell this before) condition 6 and 7 are invalid as per desired result.........